# How can I wrap company name, logo and tagline in multiple lines in the header my website?

Tags: html, css

I want to add my brand logo to the header of my website.

[image]

The first line of the logo `अEC` has three layers under it i.e. `अEC` is written 3 times on top of each other with different colors, but each layer is slightly shifted so that the layer below it is visible for the effect so I want to achieve the same effect on the website.

I also want the last two lines i.e. the brand name `अभिलाषा EDU Center` and the tag line `Find Your Right Abhilasha` should seamlessly come under the `अEC` as in the logo. All these three line should be aligned with the menu list in the header as shown in the image what I want to achieve.

I know I can be asking a lot and doing it with a completely wrong method but this is literally first time trying CSS and HTML

What I want to achieve is this

[image]

What I am able to get so far is this

[image]

The code that I am working on this

```
#logo {
        display: inline-block;
    }
    #logo h1 {
        text-align: center;
        margin-top: 0%;  
    }
```

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Abhilasha EDU Center</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.css" />
         <!-- TODO not working as expected -->
        <link rel="icon" href="images/logo.png" type="image/icon type">
    </head>
    <body class="is-preload homepage">
        <div id="page-wrapper">

            <!-- Header -->
                <div id="header-wrapper">
                    <header id="header" class="container">

                        <!-- Logo -->
                            <div id="logo">
                                <a href="index.html">
                                    <!--
                                    <img src="images/website_logo_thumbnail.png" alt="no image" />
                                    -->
                                    <h1 id="">अEC<br/>
                                    अभिलाषा EDU Center<br/>
                                    Find Your Right Abhilasha
                                    </h1>
                                </a>
                            </div>

                        <!-- Nav -->
                            <nav id="nav">
                                <ul>
                                    <li class="current"><a href="index.html">Welcome</a></li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">Dropdown</a>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Magna phasellus</a></li>
                                            <li>
                                                <a href="#">Phasellus consequat</a>
                                                <ul>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Phasellus consequat</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Magna phasellus</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Etiam dolore nisl</a></li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Veroeros feugiat</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="left-sidebar.html">Left Sidebar</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="right-sidebar.html">Right Sidebar</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="no-sidebar.html">No Sidebar</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </nav>

                    </header>
                </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the logo you can use this code that I made quickly. I pass the div where there is my text in `position: relative;` then, I put an [`::after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after) on my div that I pass it in `position: absolute;`. I invite you to learn more about positions in CSS [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position). Then I set the z-index to come on top of each other.

```
<body class="is-preload homepage">
   <div class="logo">Hello</div>
</body>

<style>
    .logo {
        color: purple;
        font-size: 46px;
        font-weight: bold;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 0;
    }
    
    .logo::after {
        content: "Hello";
        color: green;
        font-size: 46px;
        font-weight: bold;
        position: absolute;
        top: 3px;
        left: 3px;
        z-index: -1;
    }
</style>
```

To finish by talking about the alignment with your categories, I let you learn more about the [`display: flex;`](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Have a good day!